# Plotting Pairs of Ordered Pairs in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

If I have a data file with 4 columns:

```
x1, y1, x2, y2,
```

How can plot a line connecting `(x1, y1)` to `(x2, y2)` for each element (row)?

I assume it is pretty easy, but I have been playing around for an hour unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 3):

```
plot "DATA" using 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2) with vectors nohead
```

The vectors style reads four columns (*x*, *y*, *dx*, *dy*) and draws a vector from (*x*, *y*) to (*x* + *dx*, *y* + *dy*).

`nohead` prevents gnuplot from drawing the arrow head.